# Data present despite SSTable deletion

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cql3, cqlsh

I'm working on a single Cassandra 3.11.2 node(RHEL 6.5). In keyspace(named 'test'), I've a table named 'test'. I entered some rows via cqlsh and **then did nodetool flush.** I checked in the data directory to confirm that a SSTable got created. Now I deleted all the .db files(from the test.test data directory using rm *.db). 
Strangely, I can still see all the rows in cqlsh! I don't understand, how this is happening since I manually deleted the SSTable.

Given below is my keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Given below is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.test (
    aadhar_number int PRIMARY KEY,
    address text,
    name text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Given below is the output of nodetool tablestats command(after I had deleted the SSTable):

```
    Keyspace : test
            Read Count: 0

        Read Latency: NaN ms
        Write Count: 13
        Write Latency: 0.11269230769230769 ms
        Pending Flushes: 0
                Table: test
                SSTable count: 1
                Space used (live): 5220
                Space used (total): 5220
                Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                Off heap memory used (total): 48
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.7974683544303798
                Number of partitions (estimate): 255
                Memtable cell count: 0
                Memtable data size: 0
                Memtable off heap memory used: 0
                Memtable switch count: 4
                Local read count: 0
                Local read latency: NaN ms
                Local write count: 10
                Local write latency: NaN ms
                Pending flushes: 0
                Percent repaired: 0.0
                Bloom filter false positives: 0
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                Bloom filter space used: 24
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 16
                Index summary off heap memory used: 16
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 16
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 18
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 50
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 36
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 5.0
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 5
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
                Dropped Mutations: 0
```

I restarted Cassandra and only then the data stopped showing in cqlsh.

A very good [article](https://linuxgazette.net/105/pitcher.html) for understanding filesystem details in linux.

Comment: It could be (I'm not sure), because in Unix, if file is open, it's deleted when last process closes it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, filenames are just pointers (inodes) that point to the memory where the file resides. When Cassandra open the files, it holds a link to it. When you use rm to remove the file, you delete the link from the filesystem to the physical memory, but the file is still referenced by a live process and is therefore not deleted. You can easily check that with the command `lsof` (list open files). There is a flag to list for a given pid (check the cassandra pid with something like `ps aux | grep cassandra`)

Obviously, when you restart Cassandra, the file get deleted.